# Why can a question be deleted (by non-moderator users) without being closed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deletion, deleted-questions, re-open

I noticed that this question: [How to solve $\ln t = t-1$ to get $t=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3146074/9464) was deleted by three users without even being closed. 
How could that happen? Is that a system bug?

Note：it was closed and deleted before, but it was reopened later by five users (including myself). Here is the timeline: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3146074/timeline

Comment: Tangentially, the specific situation is a bit odd. A users vote to delete something only to vote to reopen it two minutes later... Maybe it was a just a clicking-error.

Answer (score 7):

This is because it is possible that a question can have five reopen votes from users with above 10k reputation even whilst it remains deleted. An old [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190443/why-can-i-vote-to-reopen-a-deleted-question) on the main meta explains some reasons why this is allowed, so it is not a system bug.

However, it is not possible to vote to close a question when it has already been deleted. As you have probably expected, for non-moderator users, neither is it possible to direct delete a question without closing it first.

As seen in the timeline, it is interesting that the question has been disputed many times, as it does not have sufficient context.

Comment: Your last sentence is completely irrelevant to what is under discussion. "as it does not have sufficient context" is merely a personal opinion. But thanks for the info.

Comment: @Jack No problem. But it is relevant to why the questions was closed (at a few points) and deleted, although it may not be what most concerns this question.